# Regular expression - ending with a character string and a slash

Tags: regex, string

I would like to write a regular expression that ends with either of the following:

/10 
or
/10/

How do I do it?

Example: something/10   or  something/10/

Comment: Where is your attempted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact mechanics will depend greatly on your environment.

For just determining a match, use the following:

```
\/10\/?$
```

Again, depending on the specific case, you may not need the '\'.
The '$' ties the match to the end of the string.

Another option that might be cleaner is this,

```
[/]10[/]?$
```